# ProjectQ - Error messages

Tags: programming

How can we get rid of runtime next error:

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Marija\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\projectq\types\_qubit.py", line 135, in __del__
    self.engine.deallocate_qubit(weak_copy)
  File "C:\Users\Marija\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\projectq\cengines\_basics.py", line 153, in deallocate_qubit
    tags=[DirtyQubitTag()] if is_dirty else [])])
  File "C:\Users\Marija\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\projectq\cengines\_main.py", line 288, in send
    raise compact_exception  # use verbose=True for more info
RuntimeError: Qubit has not been measured / uncomputed. Cannot access its classical value and/or deallocate a qubit in superposition!
 raised in:
'  File "C:\\Users\\Marija\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\projectq\\backends\\_sim\\_pysim.py", line 139, in get_classical_value'
'    raise RuntimeError("Qubit has not been measured / "'```
````

Comment: Are you asking to return a measurement value in your program? If it does then you need to make measurements in your circuit... otherwise there is nothing to be returned.

Comment: No, I'm not asking to return the measured value. I want to use the simulator and the  "get_amplitude" function after measuring and  applying the gate.

Comment: Do you have an example of the code that causes this error?

Comment: I realized that the rotation Ry causes that error, not after the first execution, but after the second, third (etc.) execution of that same code. I'm sending you an example : i.stack.imgur.com/dYShm.png  .
Also, I am sending you the same code after the first execution without error: i.stack.imgur.com/VoAIw.png  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By measuring all the qubits at the end of the code, I avoided the above-mentioned error message.